# Modify a UINavigationViewController's UIToolBar from InterfaceBuilder

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have a `UINavigationViewController`, and from InterfaceBuilder I added a ToolBar clicking on Attributes Inspector / Navigation Controller / Shows Toolbar

My `RootViewController` shows a ToolBar with a single button now, but for some reason I cannot modify it. Clicking on the toolbar selects the underlying `RootViewController`, I can add buttons by drag-dropping them, but I cannot select existing buttons (so no modifying or renaming them is possible).

How can I modify the `UINavigationViewController's` ToolBar items from InterfaceBuilder?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder, if you click on the toolbar in your .xib, it will probably not select your toolbar button but the entire toolbar. Try looking up your toolbar in the outline view left of the design view and there click in the button to select it.

Comment: My problem was that clicking anywhere on the toolbar did not select it, it selected the UIViewController instead, so I could not do anything to its contents, ever. I am starting to think it was a IB bug, since I removed the toolbar from the UINavigationViewController, but it still shows the button in IB (not in runtime, though).